# How to find MySQL records without any line breaks?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have a huge lyrics table on MySQL database and I want to find lyrics written without any line breaks. (Data does not include any HTML code like `<br>`)

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Line breaks are with `\n`?

Comment: *"How can I do achieve this?"* ... by querying the database and doing something with the response? Unless you're going to be more specific, like including the data structure, what's wrong with the way the lyrics are held in the database currently... something... there's not a huge amount anyone can do to help.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM lyrics_table WHERE lyrics_column NOT REGEXP '\n'`

Comment: I thought about line breaks with \n but it seems SELECT * FROM table WHERE lyrics NOT REGXP '\n' also doesn't work. It gathers data with new lines too. Weird..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LIKE can be used with wildcards (`%`) around a specific character or phrase you're looking for.  NOT LIKE is the opposite.  Assuming line breaks are stored as `\n`, this is a simple query that should work.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text NOT LIKE "%\n%"
```

The above query will match Windows and Unix/Linux line breaks.  However, if you need to accomodate line breaks from Mac based systems, you may also need to match `\r`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text NOT LIKE "%\n%" AND NOT LIKE "%\r%"
```

Comment: Thank you but it gathers data with new lines too. Weird... Using RegExp also has same results..

Comment: There are different line breaks for different operating systems.  Mac uses `\r` which may be what you're seeing.

Comment: I use SQLYog Community on Windows and MySQL on Debian. Only using \n or \r returns data with new lines. And I use only \n when doing INSERTs.

When I run a query with "NOT LIKE \n AND NOT LIKE \r" , it returns data without new lines but I think these are not the complete results.

Comment: Why do you think those aren't complete?  I'm assuming you're using `"%\n%"` and `"%\r%"` not just `\n` and `\r`, right?  You could always reverse it to get all the ones that do have line breaks to confirm...

Comment: I think you are right, when I tried with reversed query, it seems it returns complete results.

Answer (score 0):

[NOT REGEXP](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-not-regexp-function.php) clause in mysql will do the trick.

Try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lyrics NOT REGEXP '[\n]'
```

Comment: Thank you but it gathers data with new lines too. Weird... Not using RegExp also has same results..